# how to make akka stream source queue FIFO?

Tags: stream, akka, akka-stream

I am develop a stock trading system using akka.
I offer orderbooks into TradeQueue like below:

```
val tradeQueue = Source.queue[TradeTask](1, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
.map(task=>{
  println("TradeTask Start："+task)
  task
})
.via(ProcessA)
.via(ProcessC)
.via(ProcessC)
.toMat(Sink.foreach(task => {
     log.info("TradeTask finish："+task)
 }))(Keep.left).run()


 for (item <- 1 to 100) {
    val task = TradeTask(item)
    tradeQueue.offer(task)
 }
```

But the sequence is disordered.

**like this:**

TradeTask Start：TradeTask(1)

TradeTask Start：TradeTask(2)

TradeTask finish：TradeTask(1)

TradeTask finish：TradeTask(2)

**But I want FIFO and element enqueue before previous finish，like this**

TradeTask Start：TradeTask(1)

TradeTask finish：TradeTask(1)

TradeTask Start：TradeTask(2)

TradeTask finish：TradeTask(2)

**How to do that? Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Already a FIFO**

Your question already proves that the queue is "(F)irst (I)n (F)irst (O)ut".  As shown in the output the first element to enter the stream, `TradeTask(1)`, was the first element to be processed by the `Sink`:

```
TradeTask Start：TradeTask(1)    // <-- FIRST IN

TradeTask Start：TradeTask(2)

TradeTask finish：TradeTask(1)   // <-- FIRST OUT

TradeTask finish：TradeTask(2)
```

**Indirect Answer**

The question you are asking is completely opposite to the purpose/usage of akka-stream.  You are asking how to create an akka stream that does all of the processing serially, as opposed to asynchronously.

The whole point of akka is [asynchronous processing & communication](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/guide/introduction.html):

> Welcome to Akka, a set of open-source libraries for designing
>   scalable, resilient systems that span processor cores and networks.

If you want the processing done one-at-a-time then why go with akka in the first place?  Synchronous processing of `Iterable` elements is easily accomplished, without akka, using scala collections and for-comprehensions:

```
val functionA : Task => Task = ???
val functionB : Task => Task = ???
val functionC : Task => Task = ???

val logTask : Task => Unit = 
  (task) => log.info("TradeTask finish：" + task)

for {
  item    <- 1 to 100
  task    <- TradeTask(item)
  aResult <- functionA(task)
  bResult <- functionB(aResult)
  cResult <- functionC(bResult)
} { 
  logTask(cResult)
}
```

Similarly you can use function composition and a simplified iteration:

```
val compositeFunction : Int => Unit = 
  TradeTask.apply andThen functionA andThen functionB andThen functionC andThen logTask

(1 to 100) foreach compositeFunction
```

Comment: I have some processor writing as akka actor, In the akka stream I can expediently process via my actors like this:

 tradeQueue
.ask[TradeTask](pickMatchOrderBookHandler)
.ask[TradeTask](calculateHandler)

without akka strem,  it will make a big changing task to us.
There is any way to make akka steam implement this?

Comment: @liaolunhui I don't understand your comment.  `tradeQueue` doesn't have an `ask` method.  You can send data to the `Source`, but the `sender` information isn't preserved therefore the `Sink` can't respond to the submitting `Actor`.  I think your design should be re-evaluated.

Comment: akka streams ensures that the first message will be processed by each step first (unless you use `mapAsyncUnordered `). This is the same case than in your example with the ask pattern so not sure why it's the porpoise of your question.